# Extracting directory structure as metadata using entity recognition

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am attempting to extract values from within a url pattern and apply them as metadata by using regular expressions and entity recognition applied to the `URL`.

> URL:  https://example.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/page.html

```
Regex:
https:\/\/example\.com\/folder1\/folder2\/([^\/]*).*[^\/]*\/
```

This should extract `folder3`. This has been tested and works on `regex101` and using `reggyapp.com` (which uses google `RE2` engine, which the `GSA` uses)

> https://regex101.com/r/aF2jR0/2

However when uploading to the `GSA` as an entity recognition file it does not recognise it.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<instances>

<instance>
    <name>ignoredname</name>
    <pattern>https:\/\/example\.com\/folder1\/folder2\/([^\/]*).*[^\/]*\/</pattern>
    <store_regex_or_name> regex_tagged_as_first_group </store_regex_or_name>
</instance>

</instances>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, GSA's Entity Recognition stores the text extracted from pattern. So you can remove the following portion from the xml.
 `<store_regex_or_name> regex_tagged_as_first_group </store_regex_or_name>`.
Try without store_regex_or_name element.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now so posting this incase people are interested.

https://example.com/folder1/folder2/(\w+)/.*